PDFs generated in Chrome do not display well in Firefox
When I generate a PDF from a chromium-based browser and I dispay it in Firefox, all the shadows break.
Nevetheless either if I watch that PDF in chrome itself, or either if the PDF is generated in Firefox itself, then the shadows are properly represented.
How to reproduce

Browse to https://example.com in chrome. Note that it has a very subtle box-shadow.
Print => Save as PDF as chrome-generated.pdf
Open the Chrome-generated PDF file both in chrome and in Firefox and see results.
Repeat browsing with Firefox and generating the PDF from Firefox itself as firefox-generated.pdf
Open the Firefox-generated PDF file in Firefox and see results.

Results

This is how the original website looks like
There are very soft shadows under the box 



chrome-generated.pdf viewed in Firefox
Shadows are veeery ugly 



chrome-generated.pdf viewed in Chrome
Shadows are OK 



firefox-generated.pdf viewed in Firefox
Shadows are OK 


Question
I pretend to render the PDFs from the command line. What command-line switches should I instruct to Chrome to force it to render a fully-compatible PDF file?
Should I look into making Chrome to generate a PDF/A or similar? how?

Look at the PDF's in yet another tools, such as free Sumatra PDF (https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader, https://www.bestchromebookapps.com/sumatra-pdf-chromebook/) to help determine if the fault is in Firefox's rendering engine, or Chrome's creation of a PDF is non-compliant with standards.

In PDF XChangeViewer the PDF with problems is properly rendered. In Acrobat reader, it renders well too. Nevertheless I expect users of my website to be using multiple browsers -one of those Firefox- and opening the dynamically-generated PDFs inside the browser. So I need to "generate a PDF that renders well everywhere". Said that, Firefox renders well other PDFs generated in other generators for the same example.com page. For example when generating with PDFCreator Free, the Firefox PDF viewer renders the shadows properly.

I dont know all of Why it looks so bad but can provide some details as to how PDFs are built and rendered.
First of all Mozilla browsers like Firefox are using a PDF.js emulation of a conventional PDF viewer. Also they were in docs clear that there can be rendering differences.
When an image with transparency as per the example.com page is written direct with a PDF writer like SKIA the images are added as 2 separate objects. One is the colour data and the other a "Softmask" which is Alpha Opacity ( 0.0 - 1.0 rather than transparency) but in isolation often as an image looks like it is "All Black" see the "Black Opacity" definition in the top right details.
Here the black is defined as a very low 1.96%.

In fact it is so low that in some viewers it may be hard to see anything against a white/grey background.

How does this affect Firefox Emulation ? Well it builds a Full page PNG background image, but without any separate alpha components, (those are used for invisible text layer and additional annotations layer). It looks like a tricolour JPG but is PNG as a data blob.
Here is the Alpha Channel (no differences are visible it is pure monochrome as white) Whilst RGB channels are all similar hue generating triple layer grays.


And for some as yet unknown  reason has over-compensated with adding a greyer tonal rendering! Perhaps a bug in reading that set of values.
Thus on occasion the "PDF.js IMAGE PRE-VIEW" is unreal but the Real PDF in the cloud is still the source PDF with Alpha !
Later edit
Out of interest I tried the opposite, so use Firefox "Save as PDF" and naturally the result is different as it uses Cairo[graphics] 1.17.4  (not SKIA) to write the PDF and thus contents including images are not the same.
Most obvious the single tonal area is converted into 4 ! masks, However whilst they are the expected "Black" (Fully Transparent Alpha layers) they are 100% black thus no true grey colours at all.
So Web browsers convert from HTML into PDF will often produce different PDFs. However, some HTML objects like "Fonts" are easier to convert into  PDF objects, whilst others with "Alpha" layers are not.

